# How to update refeferences to VSConstants in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interop, code-generation, visual-studio-2017

I have a file generator tool that we've been using in Visual Studio 2013-2015 that is based on IVsSingleFileGenerator pattern in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop. I installed the Visual Studio 2017 sdk and loaded the project, but found that all the VSConsants values now lack a reference, giving the `The name 'VSConstants' does not exist in the current context` error. I've been trying to find a reference on what may havbe happened to this enum values but haven't been able to find any information on MSDN about how these values should be converted or where the constants reference may have gone.

The Constants throwing the error:

```
VSConstants.S_OK
VSConstants.E_FAIL
```

Did the reference move? Do I need to use a different set of Constants?

Comment: Comes from, say, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0.  Part of the VS SDK, it is not yet available for VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to `Assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0`
 or just install `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0` [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0/15.4.27004)

You can also check [Microsoft's migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017).

Comment: I still get this error even after referencing it: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Compiling transformation: The type name 'VSConstants' could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Framework, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

Comment: I added an additional reference to this assembly: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Framework" and it worked. I also installed .NET 4.6.1 SDK.

Comment: @metabuddy What prompted you to add xxx.Framework? It worked for me too, but I wonder how did you pick that :) ? Thanks!